# Android - Find a contact by fuzzy/approximate/similarity match

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

There are ways to find a contact by display name. For e.g. this answer [Android - Find a contact by display name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625308/android-find-a-contact-by-display-name)

But I need to find contacts with fuzzy match. For e.g. I need to return contact named "Keem" if "Kim" wasn't found.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There's no build API that can do fuzzy search over display-names, but you can do it yourself, shouldn't be that hard:

1. Read all contacts' names from the DB
2. Use a similarity string compare algorithm like Jaro Winkler to compare with the requested name
3. Return the best match

For step one, here's the code:

```
Map<String, Long> contacts = new HashMap<String, Long>();

String[] projection = {Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
// use null if you want to include hidden contacts
String selection = Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1"; 
Cursor cur = cr.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    contacts.put(name, id);
}
if (cur != null) {
    cur.close();
}
```

For step 2, you can use Jaro Winkler, or some other string distance algorithm, here's a library that can help you:
https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity